# Check whether this is the last EditText in a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Let's say in a LinearLayout we have two EditText. Android system is somehow able to tell whether an EditText is the last EditText, because the "Enter" button of the soft keyboard for the first EditText is "Next", while the "Enter" button of the soft keyboard for the second EditText is "Done". Here is the code I use to test EditText:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout editContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
    editContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    EditText firstEdit = new EditText(this);
    firstEdit.setSingleLine(true);

    EditText secondEdit = new EditText(this);
    secondEdit.setSingleLine(true);

    editContainer.addView(firstEdit);
    editContainer.addView(secondEdit);

    setContentView(editContainer);
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can programmatically know whether an EditText is the last one or not? Of course I can traverse the whole LinearLayout but I want to keep this approach as the last resort.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Next/Done labels are set with [setImeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setImeOptions%28int%29). If you want to query this value you could try [getImeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getImeOptions%28%29).

Comment: Can you provide me a simple example of using getImeOptions? I call it on firstEdit and secondEdit but both getImeOptions() return 0...

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy way would be to give your view a tag of 'last'.

```
EditText secondEdit = new EditText(this);
secondEdit.setSingleLine(true);
secondEdit.setTag('last');
```

You would get this value with `view.getTag()`

Comment: Sorry, in the real project, I dynamically add EditText so that it would be difficult to tell whether a particular EditText is the last one.

Comment: Ah I see, yes in that case Anton's suggestion sounds the best. I haven't tried it but I assume secondEdit.getImeOptions() will return either [IME_ACTION_DONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_DONE) or [IME_ACTION_GO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_GO) rather than IME_ACTION_NEXT

Answer (score 0):

You can give unique id's to EditTexts like:

```
    mEditText1.setId(1);
    mEditText2.setId(2);
```

Then you can check wheter is the focused EditText is the last one or not by comparing its id (`mEditText.getId()`) with total number of EditTexts.

Similarly you can use `setTag()` and `getTag()` method.

Comment: The same reason as to m6tt that this is not convenient for me.

Comment: So you somehow should know the total number of EditTexts, right? Then you can set tags incremantely.